# Bootstrap carousel slider content container - adding offset background

Tags: html, css, slider, bootstrap-4

Title may be a little vague, apologies. Before I start I am using pure Bootstrap latest version (https://getbootstrap.com/). There's nothing more.

Essentially, I am trying to recreate this for a client:

[image]

So far I have this:

[image]

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section>
      <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x1000" alt="">
              <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-6">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                  <h2 class="p-2" style="text-align: left !important;">Title</h2>
                  <p style="text-align: left !important;">Lorem ipsum dolor amet cornhole venmo knausgaard locavore listicle cray cloud bread poutine beard flannel irony flexitarian skateboard food truck. Pork belly enamel pin gluten-free blue bottle readymade jianbing thundercats prism, DIY mlkshk single-origin coffee jean shorts sustainable lo-fi. Before they sold out freegan subway tile migas, pug pabst PBRB. Succulents asymmetrical dreamcatcher cronut, kogi poke keytar humblebrag. Flannel fanny pack DIY iceland everyday carry. PBRB chicharrones pitchfork microdosing, raclette direct trade scenester swag artisan messenger bag air plant. Kogi polaroid mumblecore cardigan beard humblebrag poke neutra tilde slow-carb snackwave art party.</p>
                  <p style="text-align: right !important;">Read More...</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x1000" alt="">
              <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-6">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                  <h2 class="p-2" style="text-align: left !important;">Title</h2>
                  <p style="text-align: left !important;">Lorem ipsum dolor amet cornhole venmo knausgaard locavore listicle cray cloud bread poutine beard flannel irony flexitarian skateboard food truck. Pork belly enamel pin gluten-free blue bottle readymade jianbing thundercats prism, DIY mlkshk single-origin coffee jean shorts sustainable lo-fi. Before they sold out freegan subway tile migas, pug pabst PBRB. Succulents asymmetrical dreamcatcher cronut, kogi poke keytar humblebrag. Flannel fanny pack DIY iceland everyday carry. PBRB chicharrones pitchfork microdosing, raclette direct trade scenester swag artisan messenger bag air plant. Kogi polaroid mumblecore cardigan beard humblebrag poke neutra tilde slow-carb snackwave art party.</p>
                  <p style="text-align: right !important;">Read More...</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x1000" alt="">
              <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-6">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                  <h2 class="p-2" style="text-align: left !important;">Title</h2>
                  <p style="text-align: left !important;">Lorem ipsum dolor amet cornhole venmo knausgaard locavore listicle cray cloud bread poutine beard flannel irony flexitarian skateboard food truck. Pork belly enamel pin gluten-free blue bottle readymade jianbing thundercats prism, DIY mlkshk single-origin coffee jean shorts sustainable lo-fi. Before they sold out freegan subway tile migas, pug pabst PBRB. Succulents asymmetrical dreamcatcher cronut, kogi poke keytar humblebrag. Flannel fanny pack DIY iceland everyday carry. PBRB chicharrones pitchfork microdosing, raclette direct trade scenester swag artisan messenger bag air plant. Kogi polaroid mumblecore cardigan beard humblebrag poke neutra tilde slow-carb snackwave art party.</p>
                  <p style="text-align: right !important;">Read More...</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x1000" alt="">
              <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-6">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                  <h2 class="p-2" style="text-align: left !important;">Title</h2>
                  <p style="text-align: left !important;">Lorem ipsum dolor amet cornhole venmo knausgaard locavore listicle cray cloud bread poutine beard flannel irony flexitarian skateboard food truck. Pork belly enamel pin gluten-free blue bottle readymade jianbing thundercats prism, DIY mlkshk single-origin coffee jean shorts sustainable lo-fi. Before they sold out freegan subway tile migas, pug pabst PBRB. Succulents asymmetrical dreamcatcher cronut, kogi poke keytar humblebrag. Flannel fanny pack DIY iceland everyday carry. PBRB chicharrones pitchfork microdosing, raclette direct trade scenester swag artisan messenger bag air plant. Kogi polaroid mumblecore cardigan beard humblebrag poke neutra tilde slow-carb snackwave art party.</p>
                  <p style="text-align: right !important;">Read More...</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-6">
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
              </ol>
              <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="align-text-bottom"><i class="fas fa-angle-left fa-3x"></i></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
              <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="align-text-bottom"><i class="fas fa-angle-right fa-3x"></i></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The issue I am having is getting an overlay to mask the image slightly whilst being placed underneath the carousel controls/text...

Is anyone able to give some direction as to how I could do this...?

Comment: Looks like something that might be resolved by using position/z-index to get the correct layering of text/navigation/overlay.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can think of to solve this:

1. Create the tinted overlay within every slide separately. This is easy to set up, and it is easy to have the correct ordering of the image, the overlay and the caption text. The drawback is that the tinted overlay will slide with the image, while the carousel controls stay at place.
2. Create an overlay as a wrapper for the carousel controls (so for `.carousel-indicators`, `.carousel-control-prev` and `.carousel-control-next`). To me, this seems to be a more elegant way, however this is the more complex one too. The reason being that the overlay will be created in a separate stacking context as where the `.carousel-caption` is, so it is not evident to keep the correct visual ordering of the layers.

Below is my version with the second approach.
I suggest to check the live example on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/dferenc/pen/RQboLo) as the snippet feature here does not work correctly..

```css
/* This is important to make z-indexes work as expexted */
.carousel-item {
    -webkit-perspective: initial;
    perspective: initial;
}

/* This is to make the image offset */
.carousel-item img {
    padding: 1rem;
}

.carousel-panel,
.carousel-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
}

.carousel-panel {
    background-color: rgba(30,80,110,.334);
}
.carousel-overlay {
    /*
    Alternatively you could tint this, and 
    remove the coloring from `.carousel-panel`
    */
    /*background-color: rgba(30,80,110,.334);*/
}

.carousel-control-prev,
.carousel-control-next {
    align-items: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-test"></div>

            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x1000" alt="">
                <div class="carousel-overlay">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h2 class="py-2 text-left">Title</h2>
                        <p class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor amet cornhole venmo knausgaard locavore listicle cray cloud bread poutine beard flannel irony flexitarian skateboard food truck. Pork belly enamel pin gluten-free blue bottle readymade jianbing thundercats prism, DIY mlkshk single-origin coffee jean shorts sustainable lo-fi. Before they sold out freegan subway tile migas, pug pabst PBRB. Succulents asymmetrical dreamcatcher cronut, kogi poke keytar humblebrag. Flannel fanny pack DIY iceland everyday carry. PBRB chicharrones pitchfork microdosing, raclette direct trade scenester swag artisan messenger bag air plant. Kogi polaroid mumblecore cardigan beard humblebrag poke neutra tilde slow-carb snackwave art party.</p>
                        <p class="text-right">Read More…</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x1000" alt="">
                <div class="carousel-overlay">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h2 class="py-2 text-left">Title</h2>
                        <p class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor amet cornhole venmo knausgaard locavore listicle cray cloud bread poutine beard flannel irony flexitarian skateboard food truck. Pork belly enamel pin gluten-free blue bottle readymade jianbing thundercats prism, DIY mlkshk single-origin coffee jean shorts sustainable lo-fi. Before they sold out freegan subway tile migas, pug pabst PBRB. Succulents asymmetrical dreamcatcher cronut, kogi poke keytar humblebrag. Flannel fanny pack DIY iceland everyday carry. PBRB chicharrones pitchfork microdosing, raclette direct trade scenester swag artisan messenger bag air plant. Kogi polaroid mumblecore cardigan beard humblebrag poke neutra tilde slow-carb snackwave art party.</p>
                        <p class="text-right">Read More…</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x1000" alt="">
                <div class="carousel-overlay">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h2 class="py-2 text-left">Title</h2>
                        <p class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor amet cornhole venmo knausgaard locavore listicle cray cloud bread poutine beard flannel irony flexitarian skateboard food truck. Pork belly enamel pin gluten-free blue bottle readymade jianbing thundercats prism, DIY mlkshk single-origin coffee jean shorts sustainable lo-fi. Before they sold out freegan subway tile migas, pug pabst PBRB. Succulents asymmetrical dreamcatcher cronut, kogi poke keytar humblebrag. Flannel fanny pack DIY iceland everyday carry. PBRB chicharrones pitchfork microdosing, raclette direct trade scenester swag artisan messenger bag air plant. Kogi polaroid mumblecore cardigan beard humblebrag poke neutra tilde slow-carb snackwave art party.</p>
                        <p class="text-right">Read More…</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x1000" alt="">
                <div class="carousel-overlay">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h2 class="py-2 text-left">Title</h2>
                        <p class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor amet cornhole venmo knausgaard locavore listicle cray cloud bread poutine beard flannel irony flexitarian skateboard food truck. Pork belly enamel pin gluten-free blue bottle readymade jianbing thundercats prism, DIY mlkshk single-origin coffee jean shorts sustainable lo-fi. Before they sold out freegan subway tile migas, pug pabst PBRB. Succulents asymmetrical dreamcatcher cronut, kogi poke keytar humblebrag. Flannel fanny pack DIY iceland everyday carry. PBRB chicharrones pitchfork microdosing, raclette direct trade scenester swag artisan messenger bag air plant. Kogi polaroid mumblecore cardigan beard humblebrag poke neutra tilde slow-carb snackwave art party.</p>
                        <p class="text-right">Read More…</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-panel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>

            <a class="carousel-control-prev align-items-end" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="mb-4"><i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-3x"></i></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>

            <a class="carousel-control-next align-items-end" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="mb-4"><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-3x"></i></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```